# Transfering ASP.Net Website Project From One Computer To Another

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Ive been working on a project on my computer and i want to transfer it to my laptop. The project is an ASP.Net Website Project in C#. I'm using SQL Server 2012 to hold my database and the Asp.net user management tables in my database also.

What's the easiest way to do this, as i have backed up my database and copied the ASP.net website folder onto my laptop and changed data source, but I'm getting a few errors, especially on the asp.net configuration page it has also removed my roles due to the transferring.

Comment: Using Some kind of source control would facilitate this - among other positive things!

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer definitively.  We don't know how your roles are configured, for example...  And is the SQL Server a true instance of the full-blown product, or SQL Server Express?  I've never had issues copying databases and losing roles, etc, so it'd be hard to tell what's going on without access to your laptop and original servers.

Comment: The question just seems unanswerable in its present form, and to really answer it would involve discussions on setting up test environments, source control, configuration of machines, and a whole host of other things that make this question simply "too big" (overly broad) for StackOverflow.

Comment: What are the errors, if you made a backup of the database, the roles are part of the asp membership tables. in the laptop did you add the user and the permission, the name and instance of the new server and database?

Comment: Such as when im trying to create a new role on asp.net config management i get an error saying cannot find sql server. Is there no proper way to convert a project from one machine to another where it auto changes settings like (names of data source) and stuff, or do i need to just go through each error and fix them manually?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correct, what you need is to deploy the ASP.NET Membership Database to the new project location. There are set of tools and commands that you need to use.

You would need to construct a command-line like the following:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync 
 -source:dbfullsql=" [your connection string] " 
 -dest:dbfullsql="c:\temp\InsertIntoAspNetDB.sql
```

Again the exact **path and command will depend on your local configuration.**

You may get more detailed information from MSDN - [How to: Deploy a Database With a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465343%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Nope this is not what i need as the ASP.Net membership database is already in my database.

Comment: @user1638362, you need to specify your question then.